# Laravel 8 Package Development pushMiddlewareToGroup

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, package-development

After updating Laravel version from 6.0 to 8.0, the middleware pushed using `$router->pushMiddlewareToGroup` is not working.

```
//add language middleware to the web group
    $router->pushMiddleWareToGroup('web',Language::class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you wrap the code in `booted`?

```
$this->app->booted(function () use ($router) {
    $router->pushMiddleWareToGroup('web',Language::class);  
});
```

I faced the same issue and it was resolved only after calling `pushMiddleWareToGroup` in `booted`. You might also want to set the loading priority using `protected $middlewarePriority = [...];` in `App\Http\Kernel.php`